# Is there a feat for Path of War rules to use two Martial Stances at once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tome-of-battle

Is there a feat, Rogue Trick, Ninja Trick, etc that can be used with Path of War rules that lets you use two Martial Stances at once?

So far I've found [Fuse Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/fuse-styles-combat-style/) which let you use a Fighting Style & a Martial Stance at once.

Comment: For the record, the *Path of War* team also pointed out that you misunderstand Fuse Style. You can always use a stance and a style at the same time. Fuse Style just allows you to enter both in the same swift action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to do so currently is the warlord’s dual stance 20th-level capstone class feature.

I brought this question up with the Dreamscarred Press *Path of War* team, and their response was vehemently opposed to the idea of there **ever** being such a feat. The fact that it only currently exists as a capstone feature corroborates that this is how highly they value the feature. And I, for one, strongly agree: having two stances at once is extremely powerful. It should not be available to just anyone, but only to those truly dedicated to the path and at the peak of their mastery.

Answer (score 3):

The [Warlord's Dual Stance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/warlord/#TOC-Dual-Stance-Ex-) obtained at level 20 allows them to have two stances at once (but they still have to activate them independently).

If you consider Fighting Styles like Martial Stances, the [Free-Style Fighter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/free-style-fighter-fighter-archetype/) (Fighter archetype) can have two Fighting Styles active at once at level 3 (three styles at level 11 and four at level 15).